# How do I install this Ribble endurance SLR headset?

Tags: frames, headset, installation, steerer

I've installed the bearings and now I'm struggling with which order to stack things. I can't find any documentation or manual of any description. I've attached a few photos. Does anyone have any idea?

[image: headset] [image: headset]

[image: headset] [image: headset]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I believe you should start with items in https://i.stack.imgur.com/so4gwm.jpg initially. Starting with the thinnest one first, in the direction facing down as you have them in your hand.

Lastly using this on the top: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT9ppm.jpg

I would recommend using the Parktool Youtube page for more detail on Headset installation:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzaZ1sPWEuZN-I8_XT6AH8g